# When the entry field is empty, and I click the translate button, how do I make the output field return nothing in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm advancing in a translation app project, using python dictionary. There's the entry field, translate button and output field. There's an error code ("Word not found") that is displayed when the entry doesn't match the key in the dictionary. But now, when the entry field is empty and you click the button, it still returns "Word not found", which is kind of dumb. How do I return nothing when the user has input no word? Thanks. Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter. messagebox
root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')
root.title("Meta' Translator")
root.configure(background="#35424a")

#Entry widget object
textin = StringVar()

#press ENTER key to activate translate button
def returnPressed(event):
  clk()

def clk():
    entered = ent.get().lower() #Get user input and convert to lowercase
    output.delete(0.0,END)
    try:
        textin = exlist[entered]
    except:
        textin = 'Word not found'
    output.insert(0.0,textin)

#heading
lab0=Label(root,text='Translate English Words to Meta\'',bg="#35424a",fg="silver",font=('none 11 
bold'))
lab0.place(x=0,y=2)

#Entry field
ent=Entry(root,width=15,font=('Times 18'),textvar=textin,bg='white')
ent.place(x=30,y=30)

#focus insertion point on entry field
ent.focus()

#Search button
but=Button(root,padx=1,pady=1,text='Translate',command=clk,bg='powder blue',font=('none 18 
bold'))
but.place(x=60,y=90)

#press ENTER key to activate Translate button
root.bind('<Return>', returnPressed)

#output field
output=Text(root,width=15,height=1,font=('Times 18'),fg="black")
output.place(x=30,y=170)

#prevent sizing of window
root.resizable(False,False) 

#Dictionary
exlist={
    "hat":"ɨ̀də̀m", 
    "hoe":"əsɔ́",
    "honey":"jú",
    "chest":"ɨgɔ̂",
    "eye":"ɨghə́",
    "ear":"ǝ̀tǒŋ",
    }

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```py
def clk():
    entered = ent.get().lower() #Get user input and convert to lowercase
    output.delete("0.0", END)
    if len(entered.strip(" ")) > 0:
        try:
            textin = exlist[entered]
        except:
            textin = "Word not found"
        output.insert("0.0", textin)
```

Basically if the length of the string is 0 it wouldn't run the code.

Comment: @DieudonneTambah if this was the answer you were looking for please consider accepting it so that other people don't waste time coming up with the same solution

Comment: If user just enters several spaces, it still shows *"Word not found"*.

Comment: @acw1668 thx for that I fixed it. I just has to add `.strip(" ")`